# Can access sshd-server with one user, but not with an second

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, centos6.5

I am using public-private-keys to access my server. With the user "peter" I can access the server normal, but with the user "git" I can not access the server. Its always asking me for a password. If I put the password, I can login normally, but I want of course to login just with the key.

I am using for the two users the same key as checked here:

```
peter@peter-ThinkPad:~$ ssh peter@git.aerodyne
Last login: Tue Jan 28 16:29:03 2014 from 192.168.0.108
[peter@git ~]$ sudo su
[sudo] password for peter: 
[root@git peter]# diff /home/peter/.ssh/authorized_keys2 /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys2 
[root@git peter]#
```

The rights are also correct set:

```
[root@git peter]# ls -al /home/git/.ssh/
-rwx------. 1 git git  412 28. Jän 15:59 authorized_keys2
[root@git peter]# ls -al /home/git/
drwx------.  2 git  git  4096 28. Jän 16:05 .ssh
[root@git peter]# ls -al /home/
drwx------.  9 git   git   4096 28. Jän 15:32 git
```

The user git is a system user, (uid=497(git) gid=497(git) Gruppen=497(git) Kontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023) but I think there is no problem with this.

The /etc/ssh/sshd_config looks like this (just the not commented part):

```
Protocol 2
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
PermitRootLogin no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PermitEmptyPasswords no
PasswordAuthentication yes
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
UsePAM yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
X11Forwarding yes
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

I am using CentOS 6.5 as my Server. My Client is Lubuntu 13.10. The Server should host a gitlab. Its already installed and working, just the ssh-access is not working.

When I try to login:

```
peter@peter-ThinkPad:~$ ssh -v git@git.aerodyne
OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to git.aerodyne [192.168.0.204] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/peter/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/peter/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/peter/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/peter/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/peter/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/peter/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA b7:0d:7a:f6:f7:b9:c5:89:4f:17:9f:3f:4d:4b:a2:81
debug1: Host 'git.aerodyne' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/peter/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/peter/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/peter/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/peter/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
Password:
```

**Edit 1:**

```
getent passwd git
```

is giving me:

```
git:x:497:497:GitLab:/home/git/:/bin/bash
```

**Edit 2:**

I looked now in the /var/log/messages log-file, I found this error:

```
Jan 29 17:06:21 git kernel: type=1400 audit(1391011581.732:41): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=2580 comm="sshd" name="authorized_keys2" dev=sda3 ino=1005 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0 tclass=file
```

Comment: What does `getent passwd git` tell you? What is in the sshd log?

Comment: @Jenny D: `git:x:497:497:GitLab:/home/git/:/bin/bash`
in the /var/log/secure I am getting no msg. just when i quit the connection: `Jan 29 10:11:21 git sshd[1483]: Connection closed by 192.168.0.116`

Comment: I found in the /var/log/messages log-file an error (Look in the description).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the permission for the authorized_keys file should be 600.

```
chmod 600 /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys2
```

Comment: i changed it to 600, but its not working.